# Freezing frames and demux errors

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to join some video clips using ffmpeg via python script using subprocess.

Here's a section of the code:

```
def join_videos(videos):
    # videos is a list of tuples with (file_name, start_point, duration)
    path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    # create a new video file containg only the desired bit, it will be named output_N.mov
    for out_n, (file_name, start, duration) in enumerate(videos, 1):
        video_path = path + "/VIDEOS/" + file_name
        ## essentialy ffmpeg -i %PATH_TO_VIDEO -ss %STARTING_POINT -c copy -t %DURATION output_%NUMBER.mov
        command = ["ffmpeg", "-i",video_path,"-ss", str(start),"-c","copy","-t",str(duration),"output_%i.mov"%out_n]
        subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    # get the list of files with this pattern
    files = glob.glob("output_*.mov")
    # add them to a text file
    with open("to_merge_tmp.txt", 'w') as f:
        for file_name in files:
            f.write("file '{path}/{file_name}'\n".format(**locals()))
    # use 'ffmpeg' to concatenate
    command = "ffmpeg -f concat -i to_merge_tmp.txt -c copy final.mov"
    subprocess.Popen(command.split(" "), stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I issue a new video to be made using a list of file names and desired start point and duration.

ex:

```
videos = [('video1.mov', 15.5, 10), # video1, starting at 15.5 seconds, duration of 10 seconds
          ('video2.mov', 10.7, 5), 
          ('video3.mov', 0, 20)]
join_videos(videos)
```

this will generate a *final.mov* file with the parts joined together (one after the other)

The program runs fine. No errors or anything.

But when I try to play it, I have some frames that stay for too long (freezing), the audio plays normaly.

I made a second script to play it programmaticly using the [python bindings for VLC](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/)

Here's it:

```
import vlc

instance = vlc.Instance()
media = instance.media_new("final.mov")
player = instance.media_player_new()
player.set_media(media)
player.play()

while player.is_playing():
     pass

instance.vlm_release()
player.release()
instance.release()
```

With this I get a bunch of warning when playing the files.

for instance, this happens and the video doesn't play (demux error)

```
[0x7f4e64009528] mp4 demux error: MP4 plugin discarded (no moov,foov,moof box)  
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f4e64025be0] moov atom not found
[0x7f4e64009528] avformat demux error: Could not open /medi /.../final.mov: Unknown error 1052488119
```

And this happens, the video plays but with the freezing frames.

```
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x7fe76c0e5280] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fe76c0e5280] concealing 1080 DC, 1080 AC, 1080 MV errors
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x7fe76c0e5820] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fe76c0e5820] concealing 1080 DC, 1080 AC, 1080 MV errors
[0x7fe740001248] main vout display error: Failed to resize display
```

or this one, which stops the playback midway and crashes the program.

```
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Fontconfig warning: FcPattern object size does not accept value "0"
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x7f5c3c0c0000] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f5c3c0c0000] concealing 1080 DC, 1080 AC, 1080 MV errors
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x7f5c3c0c0440] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f5c3c0c0440] concealing 1080 DC, 1080 AC, 1080 MV errors
[h264 @ 0x7f5c3c0c0440] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: 12
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x7f5c3c0c09e0] decode_slice_header error
Non-reference picture received and no reference available
[h264 @ 0x7f5c3c0befa0] decode_slice_header error
```

I don't know whats going on, I'm pretty sure it's how the ffmpeg joins the files.

## EDIT

As I found [here](http://muzso.hu/2012/11/14/how-to-fix-a-broken-mp4-mov-video-ffmpeg-reports-moov-atom-not-found), the `moov atom not found` error happens when a video recorder crashes when creating the file. But I find it hard to understand why this happens and doesn't show any error when creating those files.

Comment: I'm not completely sure of what the problem is, but one thing you have to take in consideration is that seeking while copying has its problems. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Seekingwhiledoingacodeccopy.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think this might be what's causing the erros: `ffmpeg is forced to only use/split on i-frames`, but I don't know how to fix this. If I allow it to split in p-frames, it might lead to weird effects in the video.